# MariaDB: How to enable bulk insert operations

Tags: database, mariadb, bulkinsert, bulk, connector

I tried the sample from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/bulk-insert-column-wise-binding with Server 10.2.6 and Connector/C 2.3.3 and with Server 10.3 and Connector/C 3.0.1 on Windows 64bit (InnoDB), but I always get that error message:

> Server doesn't support function 'Bulk operation'

That's a clear error message, but all the docs show that MariaDB supports bulk operations. Is that a Windows problem? Or can I just enable that with a setting?

Comment: Also tried 10.2.6 with the Ubuntu version with Bash On Windows, but I get the same error message. I must miss something here...

Comment: Also tried Aria storage engine with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is only possible with 10.2.3, but this fact is not mentioned in the docs.
Just heard today from the developers that this feature will be in 10.2.7, it was to late to get merged into 10.2.6